# What grammar structure does ...在这份评估单上打分... use?

Tags: sentence-structure

There's this line in the story I read :

> “如果你能帮我们一个忙，试用我们的产品，并且，**在这份评估单上打分**，我们会再送你一瓶，以示感谢。”

How is :

在 + 这 + 份 + 评估 + 单 + 上 + 打分

Translated as : "fill the test report" / "rate this evaluation form" ???

Which part of the sentence shows "test report/evaluation form"?

Ok, I know that 评估 means "to assess" (I mean, it has something to do with evaluating), but that's a verb not a noun ㅠㅠ

Moreover, what are the functions of 份, 单, and 上 in the sentence?

I read in the dictionary that if 份 comes after 这 or 那, it refers to "nonphysical things" but I just have no idea what this "nonphysical things" mean... could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is  在 + 这 + 份 + 评估 + 单 + 上 + 打分 translated as : "fill the test report" / "rate this evaluation form" ?

"在 ~ 上"  is  a **preposition**: (on top/ on above)

> [**在** (object) **上**] = [**on top of** (object)]

The object here is "这(this) 份(classifier) 评估(adjectival phrase) 单(noun)" = "This assessment form"

> Now we know the 'object' in [在 (object) 上] is 'This assessment form', we get: [在 (这份评估单) 上]

Since we have the object, now we need a verb to make it a complete sentence. And "打分" (give marks) is the verb in this sentence.

"[在 (这份评估单) 上] [打分]" = "[preposition] + (object) + [verb]" = " on this assessment form give mark"

You can place the verb before the noun and the sentence still make sense

"[打分] [在 (这份评估单) 上]" = "[verb]+[preposition]+ (object)" = "give marks on this assessment form"

However, "在这份评估单上打分"(object before verb) emphasize the object, therefore it is preferred over "打分在这份评估单上" (verb before object), which emphasize the verb.

In this context, the writer wants to emphasize the **object** because it is more important that you know **where** to apply your action (evaluation) than **what** to do with the object

*份 as a classifier means "a portion of'; 'a set of';  which can apply to 评估单, as in "一份评估单" ---> "a (set of) assessment form"*

*We don't actually need a classifier for "form" if we are not counting or indicating the number of it. You can omit the classifier and write "在这评估单上打分" or even "在评估单上打分" here*

Answer (score 1):

「單(子)」doubles as a word for a *bill, list,* or *document/form* that you fill out.

「份」is commonly used as a measure word for *documents/reports/newspapers*.

> 在這份評估單上打分
>
> *give a rating (for the product) on this evaluation form*

The measure word is not translated, as English doesn’t use a measure word for documents/reports/newspapers.